# Get image from JSON file using JavaScript and display in HTML img tag

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm really unsure what I'm doing wrong here. My code makes sense to me, but then again I guess I'm just a beginner. Seems so simple yet I can't figure it out. Any help would be great, please and thank you.

Please read code comments for specifications of what I'm trying to do.

JSON code:

```
{"images":[
{
    "bannerImg1":"./images/effy.jpg"
}]}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { // Get data from JSON file
for (var i in data.images) {
    var output+=data.images[i].bannerImg1; // Place image in variable output
}
document.getElementById("banner-img").innerHTML=output;}); // Display image in the img tag placeholder
```

HTML:

```
<div class="banner-section">
    <!-- Image should load within the following img tag -->
    <img class="banner-img" alt="effy">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an Image object (with needed attributes) and add it to the exiting div

```js
var data = {
  "images": [{
    "bannerImg1": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXS1E.png?s=32&g=1"
  },
  {"bannerImg1" : "https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ywqe.png?s=32&g=1"
  }]
};
data.images.forEach( function(obj) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = obj.bannerImg1;
  img.setAttribute("class", "banner-img");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "effy");
  document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(img);
});
```

```html
<div class="banner-section" id="img-container">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can see how your code above works. I'm not sure why I'm so determined to get it working with JSON, I guess I thought it'd be a good way to store data...but maybe I should just stick with your way. Oh and the id thing was a silly mistake (from your previous answer before changing it), thanks for catching that.

Comment: Actually data is the JSON from getJSON call. To make it work in your code, copy paste the code from data.images to the function(data) body.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I see what you mean. Thanks a ton for the help

Answer (score 2):

1. Put a div in a body with attribute id picture e.g.`<div id="picture"></div>`
2. Append img tag to the div

   ```
   //code
   success : function(data) {
                 var returnData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);           
                 $("#picture").append("<img src=\" + returnData.img_url + "\" />");
              });
   //code if any
   ```

Comment: This isn't working for me :( perhaps I'd doing something wrong... but thanks for the help!

Comment: @mamimi Always welcome bro. What problem coming to you with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { // Get data from JSON file
     try{
      var json = $.parseJSON(data);
      for (var i =0; i< json.images.length; i++) {
        var output+=json.images[i].bannerImg1; // Place image in variable output
     }
      document.getElementById("banner-img").innerHTML=output;
     }catch{}
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, this seemed like it would've worked, but it's still not loading the image for me... thanks for the help!