# How would I change my source code to fetch images from a JSON file instead using 'img src'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch

I've created a website that has numerous img tags. I was wondering if there is a way to fetch the image urls from a JSON file instead of using the img tags without having to Start from scratch.

```
          <main>

            <div><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/pNrQaH0ATrz9wFrNpwfB1aU4MpK.jpg"/
</div>
            <div><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/mYkTq569KOtjdq5zo9mrEY6ecip.jpg"/></div>
            <div><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/7lyBcpYB0Qt8gYhXYaEZUNlNQAv.jpg"/>

          </main>
```

Comment: The `src` can point to a script that gets the image data from the JSON file.

Comment: There is no way to fetch image straight away from html, You can fetch with help of JavaScript, You can refer from this stack overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778048/get-image-from-json-file-using-javascript-and-display-in-html-img-tag

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use query selectors and the .src attribute of each DOM element to set these.

Here's my example HTML and JSON file:

HTML:

```
  <main>
    <img class="image" id="1" />
    <img class="image" id="2"/>
    <img class="image" id="3"/>
  </main>
```

JSON:

```
{
  looneyTunes: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/pNrQaH0ATrz9wFrNpwfB1aU4MpK.jpg",
  backDown: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/mYkTq569KOtjdq5zo9mrEY6ecip.jpg",
  backFuture: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/7lyBcpYB0Qt8gYhXYaEZUNlNQAv.jpg"
}
```

My javascript would look something like this:

```
const domImages = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

fetch('./images.json')
.then(res => {
       if (!res.ok) {
           throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
       }
       return res.json();
   })
   .then(json => {
for (let i = 0; i < domImages.length; i++) {
  const imageId = domImages[i].id;
  
  switch(imageId) {
    case '1': domImages[i].src = json.looneyTunes;
      break;
    case '2': domImages[i].src = json.backDown;
      break;
    case '3': domImages[i].src = json.backFuture;
      break;
  }
       })
       .catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
       })
    })
```

Breakdown:

The query selector all is finding all DOM elements with the class of "image".

```
const domImages = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
```

Then we fetch our JSON file that holds all our images.

```
fetch('./images.json')
```

We take the response and get the JSON that's contained

```
.then(res => {
       if (!res.ok) {
           throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
       }
       return res.json();
   })
```

We then create a for loop to check over each of our image DOM elements.

```
for (let i = 0; i < domImages.length; i++) {
```

We get the ID of each DOM element to check which image is supposed to be set as the source:

```
const imageId = domImages[i].id;
```

After this we use Switch to check which ID this DOM element has. If it's '1', we use the .src attribute to assign the Looney Tunes picture as it's source.

```
switch(imageId) {
  case '1': domImages[i].src = json.looneyTunes;
    break;
```

Then we just repeat for the others and catch any errors we get at the bottom

```
case '2': domImages[i].src = json.backDown;
  break;
case '3': domImages[i].src = json.backFuture;
  break;
}
   })
   .catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
   })
})
```

I hope this answers your question. Let me know if you have any issues with it or if this isn't the approach you were going towards.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, would the process be the same if the JSON file was a website. eg : https://myelearning.cavehill.uwi.edu/pluginfile.php/1629241/mod_resource/content/3/posters.json

Comment: If the url you've linked to is a JSON file, then yes it should work the same.

Comment: This is far more thorough than I was going to post. I'm only here to give out kudos.

Comment: @DuncanLutz perhaps there is a way I could share my source code with you so you can express where I've went wrong?

Comment: If you add it to a codepen and share the link I could look over it

Comment: @senecaTheMeek I appreciate it. I'm fairly new to programming (only about six months) and remember how frustrating some answers were when starting out, just trying to help where I can

Comment: @DuncanLutz https://codepen.io/noah-haynes/pen/WNdZRqo

Comment: @Mark I don't see fetch here, have you tried to integrate the example I gave above?

Comment: I did and removed it since it didn't yield any results, I just wanted to you to view what it should look like

Comment: Ive updated the code with my attempt

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't your code itself.

First, the JSON file you're referencing is behind a login which is problematic in that you can't login with fetch.

Second, it looks like you're having CORS issues which is a whole other beast in itself.

Is there any way for you to download the JSON file and host it along side the website? Or even copy the JSON into a variable in your javascript file?

Comment: Downloading the JSON file seems to be the easiest route